# How can i compress and decompress .bz2 file in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, compression

I want to decompress .bz2 file into .mdb extension and vice-versa through code.
Can someone share how to do it through code?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "show me the codez" site. It is more about answering *specific* programming-related questions. Is there any code in question that has been tried that doesn't quite work? Have any libraries been researched? (Bzip2 uses LZMA compression like 7zip, so that might be a good keyword as well.)

Comment: My apologies for the trouble.. I am new to C#.. so could not find it easily..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) supports BZip2 files.  You should be able to use their examples to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages?q=bzip2)

Note that .bz2 corresponds to bzip2 format, which explains the query in the link above.